# Программа не запускается clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, clang++

Простейшая программа

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "hello\n";

    return 0;
}
```

не включается, выдает эту ошибку:

> Выполнение предварительной задачи "C/C++: clang сборка активного файла" завершено с кодом выхода -1.

, если запускать через [image: введите сюда описание , изображения]

но запускается через [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в launch.json прописано следующее:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "C/C++: clang++ сборка и отладка активного файла",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "MIMode": "lldb",
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: clang++ сборка активного файла"
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

Скриншот терминала:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это ошибка целиком?

Comment: Да, полностью в цитате всплывающее окно, в названии ошибка, которая в терминале прописывается

Comment: Скриншот терминала покажите. Там должно быть что-то еще...

Comment: добавил скриншот

Comment: Так вот эту ошибку и надо было с самого начала показывать, а не "command failed with exit code 1". :( Ваша проблема в том, что вы программу на C++ собираете компилятором для C. Для плюсов - `clang++`.

Comment: но ведь в ```launch.json``` прописано ```clang++```

Comment: Оно там только в имени, это имя ни на что не влияет. Надо в `tasks.json` смотреть.

Comment: Разобрался, спасибо